# PHPStorm 6 не подсвечивает php в html

Tags: phpstorm, php, jetbrains

Здравствуйте!

Обновился недавно до 6-й версии шторма, и заметил, что у меня куда-то пропала подсветка php из html-файлов.

[image]

Как это исправить можно?

Comment: в настройках темы для html нет, вроде, ничего о php

Comment: да, хранить php в html дурная практика - сервер может без обработки отдать исходник, будешь всем желающим рассказывать логику генерации шаблона. Хотя бы запретить доступ в каталог, где всё это лежит.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В **Settings - File Types** выберите **Recognized File Types:** PHP files (PHP) и в **Registred Patterns** добавьте ***.html** (шаблон переназначится из HTML Files). Тогда подсветка PHP заработает в HTML-файлах (только что проверил).

Ссылки [раз](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5477673#5477673) и [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864437/how-can-i-configure-phpstorm-to-highlight-both-html-and-php-syntax-in-a-html5-f).

Answer (score 3):

*PhpStopm 9*:

*Settings* - *Editor* - *File Types*. Увидим два окна:

1. *Recognized File Types*
2. *Registred Patterns*

В окне *Recognized File Types* выбираем файл *php?* и кликаем на него. Во втором окне *Registred Patterns*, нажимаем зеленый плюс и в открывшемся окне прописываем такое `*.html`. Добавляем это и кнопку *OK*.

Теперь *php* код будет подсвечиваться в *html* страницах.

Answer (score 0):

А можете помочь в аналогичном вопросе, есть файлы .php, в нём иногда есть структура вида

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // ...
</script>
```

Однако, когда хочешь что-то например закоментировать, то PHPStorm комментирует код внутри этих тегов, как обычный html, т.е

```
<!-- -->
```

вместо

```
//
```

И естественно никакого автокомплита в js нет.